# finding quadrant from a array of objects using javascript

Tags: javascript

i have a variable of which is an array of objects ,and each object is having points. the variable is :

```
var points = [
 {x: 1, y: 1 }, 
 {x: -1, y: 1 }, 
 {x: -1, y: -1 }, 
 {x: 1, y: -1 }, 
 {x: 2, y: 2 }, 
 {x: -1, y: 2 }, 
 {x: -1, y: -2 }, 
 {x: 1, y: -2 }, 
 {x: 1, y: 6 }, 
 {x: -1, y: 4 }, 
 {x: -3, y: -1 }, 
 {x: 1, y: -1 }, 
 {x: 10, y: 1 }, 
 {x: -1, y: 11 }, 
 {x: -1, y: -1 }, 
 {x: 1, y: -1 }];
```

now i want to find the maximum vector in given quadrant.

Comment: what do you mean by `vector` and `quadrant` - all you have are `points`

Comment: Specify what you mean by quadrant and vector, because you could set up a for loop and then use conditional statements to validate the selected quadrant, and whatever you mean by vector.

Comment: when we draw x and y axis then we get 4 quadrants, so these points will be put in the each of the quadrant  according to their x and y value. and then the maximum magnitude vector from each quadrant

Comment: I'm not sure how a question with no question has 4 upvotes...

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
function max_from_quadrant( x, y ) {

    var max_magnitude = 0;
    var maxIndex = -1;

    for ( var i = 0; i < points.length; i++ ) {

      var point = points[i];
      if ( point.x*x < 0 || point.y*y < 0 )
          continue; 

      var magnitude = point.x*point.x + points.y*point.y;

      if ( magnitude > max_magnitude ) {
          max_magnitude = magnitude;
          max_index = i;
      }

    }

    return max_index > -1 ? points[max_index] : false;

}
```

Just pass in two number arguments with signs that match the quadrant you want to find the maximum in. For your set of points this gives:

```
max_from_quadrant( -1, -1 ) // {x: -3, y: -1}
max_from_quadrant( -1,  1 ) // {x: -1, y: 11}
max_from_quadrant(  1, -1 ) // {x:  1, y: -2}
max_from_quadrant(  1,  1 ) // {x: 10, y:  1}
```

Comment: `Math.pow(Math.abs ... ` is a little redundant ... just Math.pow would do ... also, for speed, compare  x * x + y * y (not using `Math.pow` ) and `sqrt` once the maximum is found .. and if magnitude isn't even returned, no need for sqrt at all :p

Comment: @Paulpro can u please explain

Comment: @amark The function takes in two arguments that specify which quadrant to search in. Then it loops through everything in the `points` array (assumed to exist in a greater scope, but could be modified to be an additional argument to the function), and compares each one that is in the quadrant you specify to find the max.